# Capture and consume input events from background python process without notifying focused window

Tags: python, linux, pyautogui

Basically I would like to write small script that would allow me to have some sort of programmable keyboard emulation. Something similar to how autohotkey on Windows is able to work.

Lets say I would like to rebind arrow keys to 'wsad' or 'hjkl' but only when CapsLook is active. I was able to detect keyboard key press with pyinput(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput ) I also can send easily various keyboard events to focused window with pyautogui (https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io) But I can't figure out a way to consume events before they are received by currently focused window.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

THIS module is one of the available tools for capturing keyboard events:

> [**`https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyboard/`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyboard/)

but it is still in the development and doesn't (yet) provide a global hook capable of capturing keyboard events at their very origin and forwarding them (or not) to the target application.

Another tool worth to look into is:

> [`myboard.py` at code.google.com downloads](https://code.google.com/archive/p/diyism-myboard/downloads)

The above script is using Python `ctypes` and `Xlib` modules which makes it possible to work directly with the system libraries written in C. It catches the keyboard events quite deep and system wide to a degree that it had crashed my OS while testing it a bit, so be warned ...

Consider also using `XGrabKey` and `XGrabKeyboard` from the X11 `libX11.so` system library:

> ```
> import ctypes
> libX11    = ctypes.CDLL('libX11.so')
> XGrabKey = libX11.XGrabKey
> XGrabKeyboard = libX11.XGrabKeyboard
> print("XGrabKey: "     , dir(XGrabKey))
> print("XGrabKeyboard: ", dir(XGrabKeyboard))
> ```

Comment: Thank you for this module. What I would like to do in it's core is to have background python script running, that would allow me to disable keyboard keys conditionally (so the foreground programs would not receive keys events).  I can see there is a discussion already on that topic on PyPi github (https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/issues/22) So maybe with time PyPi will allow to do exactly what I need

Comment: Once more, thank you! From brief look It seems that this myboard.py script is capable of accomplishing what I need, but I must admit it seems like a very rough solution for me. However it's possible there is no other better way of doing this at current moment... If no one else came with better solution in couple next days I will select your answer as a solution.

Comment: @Kubeczek I would be glad if you could provide some detailed feedback about what how and why helped to achieve what you asked for, so that I can then update the answer with more details and better explanations for future visitors of this question.